# Making my own slice function for c but getting absurd value for some slices

Tags: c, slice

I am trying to make my own slice function, but for some value like  (0,15) it is printing absurd value at the end. It is working fine for other inputs. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void slice(int a, int b, char *str) {
    char new[b - a];

    for (int i = 0; i < b - a; i++) {
        new[i] = str[a + i];
    }

    puts(new);
}

int main() {
    char str[] = { "My name is Ayush Anand" };
    slice(0, 15, str);
    
    return 0;
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: this isn't printing anything other than the str value.  Please post a [mcve] that matched your problem description and the errors

Comment: the output printed makes sense, look at the line,  char new[b-a], (ignore whether this is valid c) , what happens if a > b?

Comment: you are not leaving room for nul terminator in new or adding it, so it is not a valid string.

Comment: @MZM a>b wil not be valid input as i am trying to slice a string from index at a to index at b.As far as output is concerned i acciedently undid puts(new) to puts(str), noob mistake i guess

Comment: @ayushanan106, you're doing great, there is an uphill climb to learning C, but you'll be a better, cautious programmer.  To find issues with your code, keep small and use lots of print statements. Keep the good work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be extra room for a null-terminator. So, at the (b - a)th index, add one.

```c
for (int i = 0; i < b - a; i++)
    new[i] = str[a + i];

new[b - a] = 0; // Null-terminator
```

As mentioned in one of the comments, `a > b` is invalid. So, add a condition before the declaration of the new string.

```c
if (a > b) {
    fprintf(stderr, "a > b error");
    return;
}
char new[b - a];
...
```

Comment: `new[b] = 0` is incorrect when `a` is nonzero.  It should be `new[b - a] = 0`, and the declaration of `new` needs to be updated to have space for that.